# Unmarshal Number with Jaxb ignores real type

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a class with a field of type Number. I use this because it can be a Double or an Integer for instance.

The XML generation seems fine, it contains the real class for this field (Double):

```
<thresholdValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:double">0.2</thresholdValue>
```

I tried to add some annotations to my class but with no effect:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "numericAlarmCfgModel")
@XmlType
@XmlSeeAlso({ Number.class, Double.class, Float.class, Integer.class, Short.class, Long.class })
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) 
public class MyNewClass extends MyClass {
private Number thresholdValue;
...}
```

When Unmarshalling I have this exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Unable to create an instance of java.lang.Number
```

I'm using JAXB 2.2.11 and Java 7.

Comment: The `xsi` prefix is declared correctly? Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @lexicore Yes it's declared in an object containing this one: `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`. I simplified my Object to be a single Object with nothing else and no parent class. But the result is the same.